# Unprofessional to eat at a restaurant you are applying for a job at?

Tags: applications

If I am applying for a job at a restaurant would it be unprofessional to eat at that same restaurant after picking up an application?

Comment: Why would you think it is unprofessional?

Comment: If you are a car mechanic, would it be unprofessional to have your car repaired at a place where you are going to apply? You are lucky enough to be able to check out the place where you want to apply. It is entirely professional to take advantage of this.

Comment: Not sure about the close votes on this one. The question could hardly be any clearer and "is X professional?" is commonly accepted as a valid question here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would not only say that it's not unprofessional, but I would highly recommend it.  It will give you a chance to observe things from a different perspective and watch how people are treated there as well as the general atmosphere (at least from a public-facing perspective).

It would also give you the opportunity to try the food because it's very difficult to be enthusiastic about a place if you don't believe in the product they're selling. Additionally, it could give you something to talk about if you have an interview.  "I was here last week and I really enjoyed eating here and ..."

Answer (score 6):

No, it would be a good thing.  The only caveat is that you should act professionally while there as a customer.  Simple stuff - be polite, leave an appropriate tip, etc.

Be observant while you are there.  It gives you a better idea as to whether this is the kind of place you want to be part of.  Generally, you can tell how a company treats their employees by how the employees treat the customers.

Also, sometimes the question comes up in the interview - Are you a customer?  Now you can say "Yes".

Comment: +1 to act professionally.  It would be a mistake to think that you wouldn't be remembered as a customer, moreso if you're a bad customer.